# What causes lost updates being observed in my SQL Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, transaction, azure-sql-database, concurrency

I have a SQL Azure database with the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserBalances]
  (
     [UserId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
     [AvailableMoney] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
  );

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [UserBalancesIndex]
  ON [dbo].[UserBalances]([UserId] ASC);

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserBalanceChanges]
  (
     [EntryId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
     [UserId]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
     [PriorBalance] INT NOT NULL,
     [NewBalance]   INT NOT NULL,
     [Time]         DATETIME DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE())
  )

GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX UserBalanceChangesIndex
  ON [UserBalanceChanges]( EntryId )

GO
```

and the following code being concurrently executed via several connections the database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ChangeUserBalance] @userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                                               @change INT
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @priorBalance INT;
    DECLARE @newBalance INT;
    DECLARE @updateTime DATETIME;

    UPDATE dbo.UserBalances
    SET    @updateTime = GETUTCDATE(),
           @priorBalance = AvailableMoney,
           @newBalance = AvailableMoney = AvailableMoney + @change
    WHERE  UserId = @userId;

    INSERT INTO UserBalanceChanges
                (UserId,
                 PriorBalance,
                 NewBalance,
                 Time)
    VALUES     ( @userId,
                 @priorBalance,
                 @newBalance,
                 @updateTime );

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    RETURN 0
```

and then I run the following query:

```
SELECT TOP(1000) PriorBalance,
                 NewBalance
FROM   UserBalanceChanges
WHERE  UserId = SomeSpecificId
ORDER  BY Time DESC
```

and I often see something like this:

```
1000 995
1005 1000 <<identical
1005 1000 <<changes
1010 1005
1015 1010
```

which looks like the two concurrently running updates read the same initial value and then one update is effectively lost.

*Lost updates* are a known anomaly but [lost updates are impossible in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21111736/57428) and presumably in SQL Azure too (at least with a single "SELECT from UPDATE" statement that I have.

Yet it looks like I actually see lost updates.

Why do I observe "impossible" lost updates?

Comment: Could you give your table definition and explain the functional difference between  "AvailableMoney" vs  "PriorBalance and NewBalance"?

Comment: @EdwardDortland: I added the table definitions. The `AvailableMoney` thing is "current state" and the two others are there for historical purposes so that I can look back and find what the balance was at some specific time.

Comment: Not sure this is your issue but you seem to be relying on left to right order of variable assignment. Pretty sure this is not guaranteed.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes, that's what I'm relying on. If this doesn't work how do I get the right "SELECT from UPDATE" effect?

Comment: @sharptooth - Does Azure support the `OUTPUT` clause? `OUTPUT GETUTCDATE(), DELETED.AvailableMoney, INSERTED.AvailableMoney`? Though I don't know that this is the reason anyway.

Comment: @sharptooth, thanks for the update. disreagard my question about the functional meaning. I missed the fact that there where in different tables. Is this the actual SP or is it a simplified version? Azure's default Isolation is read commited snapshot. Which could cause anomalities if you would first select the data prior to using it in the update or insert. Another question, is the [time] value if those "duplicate" records also the same?

Comment: @EdwardDortland: The time of those duplicates is the same with "up to second" precision. The table definitions are simplified but the "SELECT from UPDATE" thing is as actual as it could be - it's a single `UPDATE` statement and MSDN claims that lost updates are impossible under any isolation level in SQL Server.

Comment: I spot a quirky update: `@newBalance = AvailableMoney = AvailableMoney + @change`

Comment: @AaronBertrand - There is a unique key on `UserId` though and for a single row the behavior of that is defined (Itzik Ben Gan uses it [as in the second example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3462957/73226)). It is not guaranteed that the `@priorBalance = AvailableMoney` will be executed before `@newBalance = AvailableMoney = AvailableMoney + @change` though.

Comment: @MartinSmith: The deal is I always see that the `UPDATE` decrements the value which wouldn't be the case if the order was different.

Comment: @sharptooth. just seconds? or also miliseconds? If the time column of those duplicate records is identical it would indicate that the problem is somewhere within the same procedure doing multiple inserts? If it was a transaction isolation/concurrency issue between two instances of the stored procedure running at the same time, the [time] column would most likely have slightly different values for each duplicate record, right?

Comment: @EdwardDortland: The problem was resolved and I added an answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I've added an answer explaining what it really was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of "other interpretation" lost update - when data is first read into local memory and then the table is updated with that data. There was another code that was intended for resetting balances of *some* users very rarely. It was something like this:

```
DECLARE @BalancesToReset TABLE
(
   UserId uniqueidentifier,
   PriorBalance int,
   NewBalance int
)

INSERT INTO @BalancesToReset( UserId, PriorBalance, NewBalance )
    SELECT UserId, AvailableMoney, dbo.ufn_ComputeNewBalance(some params)
    FROM UserBalances WHERE SomeIncorrectConditionHere

UPDATE UserBalances SET 
    AvailableMoney = BR.NewBalance FROM
       @BalancesToReset BR INNER JOIN UserBalances
       ON UserBalances.UserId = BR.UserId;

 INSERT INTO UserBalanceChanges( PriorBalance, NewBalance )
    SELECT PriorBalance, NewBalance
    FROM @BalancesToReset WHERE NewBalance < PriorBalance;
```

and this code would run concurrently with the code in question. The code was intended to `INSERT from SELECT` only a small fraction of user balances and only occasionally but because of an incorrect condition in the `SELECT` part it would select a huge portion of balances and very often. The balances that were unintentionally selected had `NewBalance` equal to `PriorBalance` and so the final `INSERT from SELECT` would not log the changes.

The `UPDATE` in the middle of this code would forcibly reset the `AvailableMoney` for many users to a precomputed value and this would introduce a "second interpretation" lost update which is possible in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for posting the update!. Be careful that since SQL Azure runs in read commited snapshot your `SELECT UserId, AvailableMoney, dbo.ufn_ComputeNewBalance(some params)
    FROM UserBalances WHERE SomeIncorrectConditionHere` might select unintended 'old' data from `UserBalances` that is in the middle of a transaction from '[dbo].[usp_ChangeUserBalance]'